# Append to issue description using jira python API

Tags: python-jira

I've been trying unsuccessfully to append to the description of a jira ticket using jira-python and the following
code:

`updated_description = description + "/n" + JIRA_object.fields.description`

where `JIRA_object` is the object containing the ticket data and `description` is the text I'd like to append.

When I look at the attributes of this object I do not see anything containing the ticket description.

Is there a way to pull a jira ticket description using the python API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `update` with the field info. See [the docs examples here](https://jira.readthedocs.io/examples.html).

```py
JIRA_object.update(description=(JIRA_object.fields.description or '') + '\n' + description)
```

`JIRA_object.fields.description` should already be updated right after that. :)